# Add users in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are setting up 4 projects on AWS. Each project has its own team. In some cases , a single person is working on multiple projects ,and is part of multiple teams.

We plan to setup 4 different AWS accounts , and add them in an organization. After that we need to send invites to our team from the account that has their project.

1. Is it possible to send email invites to people from our AWS account?
2. Can we add a single person , working on multiple projects, in multiple AWS accounts?
   If its possible , how will it work for them, will they able to sign in to AWS using a single URL and see all the project resources , or do they need to sign in using different URLs (for each project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Creating IAM users in AWS account does not ask for any emails, thus there is no automated email notifications. You have to send such emails yourself.
2. Yes, one way would be to create for that user multiple users in each account. But I think **better** way would be to have **only one IAM user** for that person, and then create [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html) in other accounts which that user can assume. The roles can be assumed using [AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html) or programmatically using AWS CLI or SDK. Access to the resources in other accounts would be controlled by the permissions defined in cross-account roles for that user.